# Generating Automated Reports from Google App Engine Dashboard

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to create a nightly email based off of some of the stats on our apps dashboard page. I've not been able to find a way to simply export the data or access any of those numbers through an api.

It appears that I could dive into the appstats code and figure out how to renderDetailsAsJson to get some stats automatically but a) most of the stats I want are not in there and b) I'm not terribly comfortable running the appstats logging full time on our production system.

I'm also considering scraping the html to get the numbers I need but I'm not looking forward to that either.

Has anyone had any success with retrieving GAE dashboard data in an automated fashion? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we are successfully parsing the Dashboard with the help of some hackery.

In `appengine-tools-sdk-1.6.1.jar` there are `AppAdminFactory` ans `ServerConnection` classes that GAE tools use to update/manage you application. There are no docs for this classes, but by looking at the source we come up with this piece of code that successfully gets any Url on the Admin pages:

```
    AppAdminFactory.ConnectOptions connectionOptions = new AppAdminFactory.ConnectOptions();
    connectionOptions.setCookies(new ClientCookieManager());
    connectionOptions.setHost("https://appengine.google.com");
    connectionOptions.setUserId("your_email@domain.com");
    connectionOptions.setPasswordPrompt(new AppAdminFactory.PasswordPrompt() {
        public String getPassword() {
            return "YourPassword";
        }
    });

    ServerConnection serverConnection = ServerConnectionFactory.getServerConnection(connectionOptions);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // provide some parameters (see url when visiting Dashboard)
    params.put("app_id", "s~idd-backend")

            // provide the Url
    String response = serverConnection.get("/dashboard", params);
```